# What is an intuitive interpretation of the steps in the long division $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$?

Tags: calculus, polynomials

I recently asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4511142/spivak-how-do-we-divide-1-by-1t2-to-obtain-frac11t2-1-t2t4-t), about how to perform the division $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$.

The accepted answer did provide the technique that is used. I did not, however, understand how that technique worked.

The end result was the synthetic division

$$\begin{array}{c|ccccccccc} & t^0 & t & t^2 & t^3 & t^4 & t^5 & t^6 & t^7 & t^8\\ & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\-1 & & & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1\\\hline & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & \color{red}{1}\end{array}$$

I did not even know about synthetic division until my aforementioned recent question, and apparently it does the same thing as long division, which I am accustomed to using. I prefer the long division because I can think through what is happening in each step, and I want to stick with it.

In the context of long division, it seems like the following is happening

[image]

If we wanted to, we could perform the calculation differently, as below for example

[image]

The first option looks nicer.

What exactly are we trying to do in each step when we do the long division the first way?

For example, to obtain a $1$ at the top, normally we would be asking "how many times do I have to multiply the divisor term with the highest degree to get the dividend term with the highest degree?". But we're not doing that here, right?

Seems that $(1)$ is used (for example, when computing Taylor polynomial of $\arctan$) instead of $(2)$ simply because it is a better-looking expression.

If this is the case, then perhaps there is no specific intuitive reason why the steps in the first way are the way that they are.

I'm going to guess we could do everything we can do with $(1)$ with $(2)$, and with any other answer to the long division that we choose to use.

Comment: Long division tries to remove terms from the left side. Your second division "works," in that it is an accurate formula, but it doesn't say much as the number of terms goes to $\infty.$ Your "error" is very large when $|x|<1,$ while the standard long division error, $\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^2}$ goes to zero as the number of terms goes to infinity.

Comment: This likely doesn't help, but synthetic division is best used when dividing by a monic linear polynomial, e.g., something like $\frac{x^2 - 5x + 7}{x - 1}$.

Comment: For instance, if your long division $\frac1{13}$ didn't have an error term going to zero the more we divided, we wouldn't like it.

Comment: @SeanRoberson it works fine here as a technique for learning about how power series work. It is not clear what your comment is intending to do if not help.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Out of all the infinite ways we could perform this long division, is the fact that the first one above is the convenient one a coincidence or was there some a priori method we intended to use to perform the long division that then resulted in the first result above? What I mean by that is: when we divide $5x^5+x^2+x+1$ by $x^2+1$, a priori we know that at each step we are going to try to find the multiple $y$ such that $(x^2+1)y$ equals whatever remainder we have at that step. In the case of the long division of my question, it seems we are not doing this anymore.

Comment: In general, division tries to get $a/b$ as a quotient and a remainder, where the remainder is "smaller" than $b.$ But the context of what is "smaller" is different. This sort of polynomial division is treating $x$ as small, so a polynomial is smaller if it has more powers of $x$ as a factor. Under this sort of division, there is always a unique quotient and remainder which makes the remainder the smallest it can be, under this definition of "small." So it is not arbitrary.

Comment: It's worth trying integer long division to get the decimal expansion for $\frac1{1+10^2}.$ $$\frac{1}{101}=0.009900990099\dot=0.0100010001\dots  -0.000100010001\dots$$

Comment: (Aside: Standard polynomial division treats $x$ as "large," so we want the remainder polynomial to have smaller degree than the denominator. But this isn't standard polynomial division.)

Comment: A step in the long division algorithm is intended to produce a strictly decreasing sequence of remainders, according to some agreed ordering on the remainders. For formal power series, the agreed ordering has $1 + \dots > x + \ldots  > x^2 + \ldots > x^3 + \ldots > \dots$ (so the long division algorithm should eliminate a constant term, then eliminate a linear term and so on). Your second algorithm doesn't achieve this.